# Using the Stroke CSS property on my SVG in a React Native App

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, svg

I have imported an svg using the react-native-svg-transformer into my react native app and svg is rendered fine. I would like to change the stroke & stroke width of this svg image.

This can be accomplished by doing the following in my .tsx file:

```
<Car stroke='black' strokeWidth=2></Car>
```

However, I have to specify the stroke and strokeWidth instead within my linked style.js files, however whenever I simply write:

```
Car: {
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 2
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
Invariant Violation: "stroke" is not a valid style property
```

However, stroke and strokeWidth are valid css properties.

Comment: SVG as a XML code is not supported by `Image` component in React Native. You might be looking for some library like [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg).

Comment: I'm currently using the react-native-svg-transformer which is dependant on react-native-svg. These libraries give you the 'stroke' props but do not mention how to do this within css.

Answer (score -3):

You should use curly braces for the value of `strokeWidth`.

Instead of:

```
<Car stroke='black' strokeWidth=2></Car>`
```

try using:

```
<Car stroke={'black'} strokeWidth={2}></Car>
```